# How to ignore files ending with ~ in git?

Tags: git

In git-status, I have

```
sandbox.sh
sandbox.sh~
```

I would like to ignore the latter file.

How can you ignore files with extension of some snake ~?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just add `*~` to your `.gitignore`.

This will ignore all the files ending with `~`

Answer (score 7):

The pattern to ignore anything ending with `~` is `*~`. These files are probably left as backup by your text editor, hence are specific to you, and not to the project. The best is to add this `*~` to your user-wide ignore file, i.e. `~/.config/git/ignore` (create it if it does not exist) on recent enough versions of Git.

Alternatively, you can add it to your project's `.gitignore` file, but

1) It will add noise to the project's history. If N developers each use a different text editor with different conventions, you'll end-up with N lines in your `.gitignore` file.

2) You would have to do it for each project you contribute to.

Comment: I just added this pattern to my .gitignore_global which is set to globally ignore those files in my system.